# Does modularity in code, reduce performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am having an argument about performance of certain code when executed and it's relation with the degree of modularity of that code.

I know modularity has been a goal for most new generation(post mainframe era) softwares but what strikes me is that when prioritizing the modularity of code we will have to deal with multiple extra "calls" and duplicated ones between modules, components, external/internal services,... . these calls would lower performance of the execution of that code, especially if it in continuous execution ( server side code ).

My biggest programming experience was with Javascript and some modularity promising frameworks clearly expose the performance issues, I am pretty sure this has lower impact when it comes to lower level programming languages.

so I would love to know if this is an issue when it comes to javascript client and server side?

Comment: In Javascript specifically it probably doesn't make too much of a difference either way. Javascript is too high level for you to do much about minute performance issues. Internal compiler optimisations do more for performance than you deciding for or against an additional function call. Once you start talking about something like C that becomes more of an issue.

Comment: So the issues are more relevant in low level languages